# Process() called from from Pylons creates a fork

Tags: python, pylons, multiprocessing

I'm trying to create a background process for some heavy calculations from the main Pylons process. Here's the code:

```
    p = Process(target = instance_process, \
                args = (instance_tuple.instance, parent_pipe, child_pipe,))
    p.start()
```

The process is created and started, but is seems to be a fork from the main process: it is listening to the same port and the whole application hangs up. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Process IS a fork. If you look through it's implementation you'll find that `Process.start()` calls a fork. It does NOT, however, call any of the `exec` variations to change the execution context.

Still, this may have nothing to do with listening on the same port (unless the parent process is multi-threaded). At which point is the program hanging?
I know that when you try shutting down a python program without terminating the child process created through multiprocessing it will hang until the child process terminates.
This might be caused if, for instance, you do not close the pipe between the processes.

Comment: So what is the best way to start a background process? Or maybe it is better to start a thread? The goal is to create a precess/thread that will be waiting for incoming commands and perform some heavy calculations for quite a long time.

Comment: Python threading is degenerated. The Python interpreter only runs a single thread of execution at a time, switching between threads every 100 commands (exactly) and print would hang the entire process (read about python [GIL](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock)). I wouldn't recommend threading in Python.

As to processes, You should simply use `p.terminate()` and `p.join()` after the calculations are complete

Comment: These calculations can invole lots of data (500-700 Mb) and it won't be good to load it every time user wants to do something with it. What is I start a process using subprocess.Popen() function?

Comment: It's difficult to suggest a specific solution without a specific problem. Popen is usually used to invoke a 3rd party program and get it's stdout into a file descriptor in your program. The main question is what do you want the process to do...

Comment: I need my process to be a computing instance for an online computer-aided engineering system, i.e. it should be able to load the initial data, perform computations such as mesh building and mechanical calculations without blocking the main Pylons thread.

Comment: You might want to generate some sort of an RPC (Remote Procedure Call) mechanism for your calculations process.
The `multiprocess.Pipe` and `multiprocess.Queue` objects are capable of transmitting pickleable objects between the processes. This way you can transmit touples, for instance, containing a method, a touple of arguments and a dict of keywords. and receive back a touple containing a boolean value and a return object. If the first part is True then the execution was successful and the object is returned, if it's False then the execution failed and the object is raised as an Exception.

Comment: I know that. The question is how to create processes so that they would be separate from the parent process so that wouldn't listen to the http port.

Comment: @immortal let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2666/discussion-between-ivan-gromov-and-immortal)

Comment: You can kill the other threads and close file descriptors as the first thing the child process does.